# Include js/css module in Rails in vendor/lib dir

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, css, sprockets

I have a Rails 3.1 project and I'm trying to include a jQuery plugin that has both js, css and image files and i've put them under `vendor/assets/chosen/{images,javascripts,stylesheets}` and i've added index.css and index.js to the respective dirs.

Then i try to include the plugin in application.css and application.js with this:

application.js:

```
    //= require chosen
```

application.css

```
    /*
     *= require chosen
    */
```

But when i load the page i get this error:

```
couldn't find file 'chosen'
  (in /..../app/assets/stylesheets/screen.css:8)
```

According to [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization) page under 2.1.2 you should be able to do this with at least the lib dir (which i've tried, same result). Anyone has any tips?

**Update:**
When i inspect assets.paths in the rails console `vendor/assets/chosen` is included.

Comment: The version you mentions that includes a whole package in the `lib` folder mentions that in order for that to work you'll need an `index.js` file in the plugin root directory. Could it be that chosen doesn't have one?

Comment: ...and why not just use the already existing rails plugin instead? https://github.com/bseanvt/chosen_rails

Answer (score 0):

Try to write related paths to your plugin's files. For example (that's how I included colorpicker in my project):

```
//= require ../../../vendor/assets/javascripts/colorpicker #in application.js
*= require ../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/colorpicker #in application.css
```

And for you it would be something like this:

```
//= require ../../../vendor/assets/javascripts/chosen #in application.js
*= require ../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/chosen #application.css
```

Also make sure your paths are visible for Rails. (config.assets.paths)

Comment: Even though relative paths might work it makes very ugly includes for deeply nested files and the way i do it should work according to the rails guides.

Sorry, forgot to mention in my post that i had already inspected assets.paths in the rails console and vendor/assets/chosen is included there.

Comment: It is a good practice to keep your external javascripts and css in separate folders, named: `vendor/javascripts` and `vendor/stylesheets`. Try to put them inside theese folders and add `require` statements inside application.(js/css). It should work.

Comment: They are under separate folders under `vendor/assets/chosen`. I did think about putting them under `vendor/assets/javascripts` and `vendor/assets/stylesheets` but since it's a self contained module written by someone else i'd much rather keep the files grouped together in some way to make it clear to future maintainers that the files belong to each other. Another option would be to put them under something like `vendor/assets/javascripts/chosen` but that would still leave them fairly scattered.

Answer (score 0):

```
//= require chosen
```

The above code which you have added in application.js tells Rails to look for a file named "chosen" in assets path. Since you don't have a file called "chosen", rails is complaining "file not found", which is correct. What you need is require_tree

```
#application.js
//= require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/chosen/javascripts

#application.css
*= require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/chosen/stylesheets
```